# MvcSiteMap breadcrums don't visible in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breadcrumbs, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I have the two similar views in which MVCSiteMap breadcrums are unvisible. On the others pages the same code works. Help me please to figure out why these two views don't show breadcrums.
Mvcsitemap code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Главная" controller="Home" action="Index" key="Home">

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Каталоги" controller="Products" action="Index" key="Products" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Продукция" controller="Products" action="ProductList" key="ProductList" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Новинки" controller="Products" action="ShowNewest" key="ShowNewest" />
    <!--Education-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Обучение" controller="Education" action="Index" key="Education">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Видео" controller="Education" action="Video" key="Video" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Мастер-классы видео" controller="Education" action="Video_MasterClass" key="Video_MasterClass" />


      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Отзывы участников" controller="Education" action="FeedbacksParticipants" key="FeedbacksParticipants">

        <!--THIS IS THE FIRST PROBLEM-->     
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Отзыв участника" controller="Education" action="OneFeedbacksParticipants" key="OneFeedbacksParticipants" />
      </mvcSiteMapNode>  


      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Полное рассписание семинаров" controller="Education" action="AllSeminars" key="AllSeminars" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Семинары по уходу за лицом" controller="Education" action="FaceSeminars" key="FaceSeminars" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Семинары по уходу за телом" controller="Education" action="BodySeminars" key="BodySeminars" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Информация о интересующем семинаре" controller="Education" action="ShowOneSeminar" key="ShowOneSeminar" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Тренинги для руководителей" controller="Education" action="TrainingsForChiefs" key="TrainingsForChiefs" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Тренинги по продажам" controller="Education" action="TrainingsForSalers" key="TrainingsForSalers" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Информация о интересующем тренинге" controller="Education" action="ShowOneTraining" key="ShowOneTraining" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <!--News-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Новости" controller="News" action="AllNews" key="AllNews" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Новость" controller="News" action="News" key="News" />
    <!--Partners-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Партнеры" controller="Partner" action="AllPartners" key="Partners" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Партнер" controller="Partner" action="Partner" key="OneOfPartners" />
    <!--About company-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="О нас" controller="Home" action="AboutUs" key="AboutUs" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="О бренде" controller="Home" action="AboutBrand" key="AboutBrand" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Пресса" controller="Social" action="Press" key="Press" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Статья" controller="Press" action="Press" key="Article" />

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Отзывы" controller="Social" action="Feedback" key="Feedback">

      <!--THIS IS THE SECOND PROBLEM-->     
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Отзыв подробнее" controller="Social" action="OneFeedback" key="OneFeedback" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>  


    <!--Contacts-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Контакты" controller="Home" action="Contacts" key="Contacts" />
    <!--Sertificartes-->
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Сертификаты" controller="Sertificates" action="Index" key="Sertificates" />

  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

Code in controller (Education):

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Отзыв участника", ParentKey = "FeedbacksParticipants")]
        public ActionResult OneFeedbacksParticipants(Int32 id)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Отзывы участников";
            ViewBag.Description = "Отзывы об обучении в Астрамед";
            ViewBag.Keywords = "Астрамед, отзывы, обучение, семинары, тренинги, лицо, тело, косметика";
            FeedbackOfParticipantManager manager = new FeedbackOfParticipantManager();
            FeedbackModel model = manager.GetFeedback(id);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Code in controller (Social):

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Отзыв подробнее", ParentKey = "Feedback")]
        public ActionResult OneFeedback(Int32 id)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Отзыв подробнее";
            ViewBag.Description = "Отзывы об Астрамед";
            ViewBag.Keywords = "Астрамед, Tegor, отзывы";

            FeedbackManager feedbackManager = new FeedbackManager();
            FeedbackModel model = feedbackManager.GetFeedback(id);
            return View(model);
        }
```

In views I have the next code:

```
<div class="breadcumbs">@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()</div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have not defined what to do with the `id` parameter in your configuration. By default, you are expected to make a node for each possible `id`.

That probably wouldn't be practical in this case. The other option is to configure a one-to-many relationship by forcing every `id` to match using PreservedRouteParameters.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Отзыв участника", ParentKey = "FeedbacksParticipants", PreservedRouteParamters="id")]
public ActionResult OneFeedbacksParticipants(Int32 id)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Отзывы участников";
    ViewBag.Description = "Отзывы об обучении в Астрамед";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Астрамед, отзывы, обучение, семинары, тренинги, лицо, тело, косметика";
    FeedbackOfParticipantManager manager = new FeedbackOfParticipantManager();
    FeedbackModel model = manager.GetFeedback(id);
    return View(model);
}

[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Отзыв подробнее", ParentKey = "Feedback", PreservedRouteParamters="id")]
public ActionResult OneFeedback(Int32 id)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Отзыв подробнее";
    ViewBag.Description = "Отзывы об Астрамед";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Астрамед, Tegor, отзывы";

    FeedbackManager feedbackManager = new FeedbackManager();
    FeedbackModel model = feedbackManager.GetFeedback(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

References:

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics
http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position

> NOTE: You should only declare the node once, either in XML or as a .NET attribute.